Power Query Question: PDF with Multiple Identical tables Requiring Transpositions before merging into one table, How can I do this efficiently?
Hi everyone before I get into it here's a condensed version of what I'm trying to accomplish. My goal is to convert a series of PDF tables into single rows and then combine all of them together into a large database.
I have a PDF that contains an image with a summary table on the top of each page. Some of these PDF's can reach several hundred pages in length but they all contain the same information per page; an image with a summary table.
Each Table comes in like this (Dummy Data) Which is nice because it's always uniform. But due to the way the tables are organized, it requires some transposition and transformations before I can nicely group up all of the header's with their respective data underneath.
Here's a sample of what the tables I'm working with will look like.



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Client #
1234-123
Account
9999999


Batch #
123456789
Amount
9999999


--------
--------
--------
--------


Date
YYYY/MM/DD
--------
--------



My current solution is to import all of the tables as individual queries from the source PDF.
Since each table is identical in structure, I've been applying my transformations to one file, and then copying the Advanced Editor Query and pasting it into the other tables. For some reason the Helper Sample file is not working when I do the original import... so this has been my work around for that.
As for the table transformations. The current table looks like this on import.



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Client #
1234-123
Account
9999999


--------
--------
--------
--------


Batch #
123456789
Amount
9999999


--------
--------
--------
--------


Date
YYYY/MM/DD
--------
--------


--------
--------
--------
--------



But after my transformations I'm able to get it to look like this, which is exactly what needs to happen.



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D
Column E




Client #
Batch #
Account #
Amount
Date


--------
--------
--------
--------
--------


1234-123
123456789
9999999
9999999
YYYY/MM/DD



I've done this by first transposing the table, then I add two custom columns using the report.field formula to pull the Account & Amount information into separate rows, Once the structure is sound I remove the extra two rows at the bottom of the table.
Once this is done (and this is the part I am trying to address with this post) I use the Advanced editor to copy the query and apply it to all of the other tables advanced editor queries to recreate the steps.
Once all of the tables look the same I use the Append Queries function and then go for lunch lol.
While this solution does work, some of the PDFs contain hundreds of tables, which makes copy & Pasting the query quite tedious as I need to do it across all 100 tables. I have tried importing the entire PDF as one big table but since the original import has it's header's split across two columns transposing things becomes more difficult. If that's where my solution lies I've included a sample of what the data imports as when imported as one big table.



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Client #
1234-123
Account
9999999


Batch #
123456789
Amount
9999999


--------
--------
--------
--------


Date
YYYY/MM/DD
--------
--------


--------
--------
--------
--------


Client #
1234-123
Account
9999999


Batch #
123456789
Amount
9999999


--------
--------
--------
--------


Date
YYYY/MM/DD
--------
--------



I realize this is a big ask but if anyone has any resources or solutions to share, I'd be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

You could generate a list of tables (files) and then use List.Accumulate to process each file, combining it with the previous.

This would convert your one big table. It works under the assumption that having Client in column A signals a new section
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column A],"Client") then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"data", each 
    let Transform1 =Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(_,{"Column A", "Column B"})),1) &
            Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(_,{"Column C", "Column D"})),1),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Transform1, each not Text.Contains([Column1] ,"----"))
in Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Transpose(#"Filtered Rows")), type table }}),
Combine =Table.Combine(#"Grouped Rows"[data])
in  Combine


Alternate method if you are absolutely sure about placement in the grid of each item
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column A],"Client") then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"data", each #table({"Client#", "Account", "Batch","Amount","Date"},{{_{0}[Column B],_{0}[Column D],_{1}[Column B],_{0}[Column D],_{3}[Column B]}}), type table }}),
Combine =Table.Combine(#"Grouped Rows"[data])
in  Combine


Not a really big deal, but I like using https://gist.github.com/Mike-Honey/47e29c9f5cbac2f1c259ac961621cf36 to add a running count of "Client #" to create a key for grouping.

you should add a solution to show us how that works!

Added. The logic is almost identical to yours. I just like the "add running count" code. but it is actually longer than your version.

Thanks for the responses and sorry for the delay in getting back for these.
This approach is working well with the dummy data but it's not exactly translating to my proper file. My fault on trying to rush creating a table through this forum there.
Regardless, I'd like to figure out how your solution worked so I don't need to revisit it in the future.
I was able to follow the code up to the #Grouped Rows section. (also the #Filled Down, it seemed redundant when I tried to recreate the steps on my own).
Can you explain how the #grouped Rows formula is working? Thanks!

Below code follows almost the same logic as horseyride's answer.
I also assumes that having Client in column A signals a new section.
Except that I create the "grouping column" differently.
I used below code I found in Github to add a running count of the word "Client #" in column A for the grouping key:
https://gist.github.com/Mike-Honey/47e29c9f5cbac2f1c259ac961621cf36

let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Column A] <> "--------" or [Column B] <> "--------" or [Column C] <> "--------" or [Column D] <> "--------"),
  AddIndicator = Table.AddColumn(FilteredRows, "Indicator", each if [Column A] = "Client #" then 1 else 0),
  RunningCount = List.Skip(List.Accumulate(AddIndicator[Indicator],{0},(cumulative,indicator) => cumulative & {List.Last(cumulative) + indicator})),
  TableType = Value.Type(Table.AddColumn(FilteredRows, "RunningCount", each null, type number)),
  AddRunningCount = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(FilteredRows)&{RunningCount}, TableType),
  Grouped = Table.Group(AddRunningCount, "RunningCount", {"SubRecord", each Record.Combine({Record.FromList([Column B], [Column A]), Record.FromList([Column D], [Column C])})}),
  CleanRecord = Table.AddColumn(Grouped, "CleanedRecord", each if Record.HasFields([SubRecord], "--------") then Record.RemoveFields([SubRecord], "--------")  else [SubRecord]),
  Combined = Table.FromRecords(CleanRecord[CleanedRecord])
in
  Combined


Interesting. Honestly the easiest thing to do if we just think there is always groups of 5 rows is to just use #"Added Index" = Table.TransformColumns(Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),{{"Index", each  Number.IntegerDivide(_, 5), Int64.Type}}),

@horseyride yes, that is probably the most suitable for this specific case. and it is much more straightforward.
